# How to prove that a function is a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-explanation, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Here is my given definition of a function:

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then a function $f$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $A\times B$ such that
$$\forall a\in A\, \exists\, !\, b\in B\big((a,b)\in f\big)$$ Specifically, a binary operation $\star$ on $A$ is defined as : $$\star\colon= (A\times A)\to A $$
and $$\star\subseteq (A\times A)\times A $$

My question is how to go about proving the uniqueness property for a function, specifically a binary operation. I can demonstrate the existence property of $b$ just fine, but here is my definition for proving existence and uniqueness: $$\exists x\big(P(x)\wedge \forall y(P(y)\longrightarrow y = x) \big) $$

$\bullet$I realize that there are other equivalent ways of writing this and I was wondering what the best way to go about proving this was and/or if there are better/more complete definitions for these terms.

For example, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)\colon=x^2$. So, I need to show that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a unique $y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x,y)\in f$ and $f\subseteq \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to prove that $f$ is a function.

Existence: Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, because $\mathbb{R}$ is a field and is closed under multiplication, $x^2=x\cdot x\in\mathbb{R}$. So $y=x^2$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$ and $(x,y)\in f$.

Uniqueness: Let $z\in\mathbb{R}$. $P(y)$ in this case is $P(z)$ and requires me to show that for all $z\in\mathbb{R}$, $z^2$ implies that there exists an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $x=z$. Both $x$ and $z$ are in the real numbers and $x^2=y$ exists.

$\bullet$I am lost from here. What should I do now? I feel like this process can even be made into a procedure, but I am not seeing a key step. My wording in the last step may be incorrect as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R : y=x^2\}$. To prove that $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (that is, $f$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$) we need to prove two things:

- for any $x \in \mathbb R$ there exists $y \in \mathbb R$ such that $(x,y) \in f$,
- if $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,z) \in f$, then $y=z$.

Now, to prove the first one, let $x \in \mathbb R$ and consider $y = x^2$. To prove the second, suppose $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,z) \in f$. This means, by definition of $f$, that $y=x^2$ and $z=x^2$. But then $y=x^2=z$.

Hence, $f$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$!

Comment: Thank you for simplifying this. My teacher's notes looked so confusing.